# How can I create a biplot with factoextra after using varimax rotation in R?

Tags: r, rotation, pca, biplot

I have performed a PCA on my data set with `prcomp()` and then used `fviz_pca_biplot()` (package `factoextra`) to create a nice biplot (including different colors by group, in my case four different sites).

It was suggested to me to use varimax rotation to increase the interpretability of the PCA axes. I've tried many options including `varimax()`, or a different package (`psych`), but I was not able to get the same nice biplot I produced with `factoextra`.

Does someone know whether it is at all possible to create a biplot with `factoextra` after using the `varimax()` function in R?